# Firefox extension interacting with the DOM

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon

May be my logic is wrong but I'm trying to send and receive datas between my extension and the content.

So I start with something like this to send data from my content to my extension :

```
var images_elements = [];
tabs.activeTab.attach({
  contentScript: "postMessage(document.getElementsByTagName('img'));",
  onMessage: function (message) {
    images_elements = message;
  }
});
```

Obviously, it doesn't work.
How can I do something like this ? And How can I did it in the other way, example make something on this elements after making a **require("sdk/request").Request** and replace them in the content.

Comment: +1. Want to do something same sometime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send data, but the API accept only data that is [JSON-serializable value](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/dev-guide/guides/content-scripts/using-port.html#json_serializable).

DOM nodes are not in that category, that's why it doesn't work.